# Matlab Codgen error when generating MEX file

Tags: matlab, codegen

I'm having some problems in generating a MEX file using Matlab Codgen. I'm not able to identify the reason of this error, I get an error message that doesn't reflect a real situation, in my understanding.

The function that I want to convert is the following:

```
function section = locateCupPlanInSec(separatorInterval,currentAngle)

lowerSep = 1; 
upperSep = size(separatorInterval,2);
section = 0;    % init value

while (upperSep-lowerSep) > 1

    middleSep = (upperSep+lowerSep)/2;
    middleAngle = separatorInterval(:,middleSep);

    if currentSliceAngle > middleAngle
        lowerSep = middleSep; 
    else
        upperSep = middleSep;
    end

end

section = lowerSep;
```

Where currentAngle is a double(1x1) and separatorInterval is a array of double(1x:inf). When I use the codgen I don't get any problem in Generating trial code and Building MEX. But in running test file with MEX I get the following:

```
Error using TestBenchManager.executeTestBench (line 0)
Error evaluating test code.

Caused by: Undefined function or variable 'separatorInterval'.

Error in runTestExecute (line 0)

Error in runTestBench (line 0)

Error in runTestBench (line 0)
```

But separatorInterval is defined and I can see it in the workspace. What am I doing wrong? Thanks